# Command to return value if variable exists?

Tags: php

I often find myself writing something like this:

```
$val = (isset($dog->owner->name)) ? $dog->owner->name : "no owner";
```

Because PHP throws an error if you try to evaluate a variable that does not exist, the following will not work (PHP 5.3 and above for the new shorthand ternary syntax):

```
$val = ($dog->owner->name) ?: "no owner";
```

You can achieve the above if you turn off `E_USER_NOTICE` reporting, which is not something I want to do.

Is there a PHP command that will return the value of a variable if it is defined?

Comment: P.S. "You're doing it wrong" comments welcome.

Comment: Does `isset()` or `is_null()` help ? Note they work differently.

Comment: No, they both return boolean values

Comment: You can write your own function to do so. PHP library does not have single command to achieve your goal, I think

Comment: You're doing it right. There is no better way in php and that's why libraries like [symfony/property-access](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html#reading-from-objects) exist

Comment: What's wrong with your Shorthand ternary version? It looks good, you can add `isset` to it and its all set

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky the short-short ternary version will throw an error if the variable is not defined, and if you add an isset it will not return the value.

Answer (score 3):

PHP doesn't have anything like this, but you can create your own.  The key is passing by reference:

```
function getVar(&$var, $default=null) {
    if( isset($var) ) return $var;
    else return $default;
}

$blah = getVar($blah, "my default value");
```

Comment: It works unless I don't have error reporting turned on  :)  It'll work for objects too e.g. $blah = getVar($obj->val, "my default value");

Comment: This is really interesting. It works for basic variables and StdClass objects without magic methods. However if you try to apply it to nested properties combined with magic methods you will receive a "Indirect modification of overloaded property" error. Kudos for the innovative solution. I will upvote this as it may help others.

Comment: What does your call to the function look like?  Are you trying to assign the same value you're testing?  Maybe that's the indirect modification?

From what I've read, the "indirect modification of overloaded property" comes from using overloaded array properties.  This might be useful:  https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39449

Comment: I tested a few options, passing nested properties on a vanilla StdClass object workds fine, but passing nested properties on an ORM object with getters fails, where isset still behaves "normally"

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no command to check if the variable has a value assigned without doing what you've already done. You're going to have to either perform a check or explicitly make sure your variable has a value. Add the owner's name as a parameter in the class constructor or give it a default assignment on object creation. You can also create a method that performs this task so you can reuse the code.

Answer (score -3):

You can try [Error control operaors @](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

```
@$val = $dog->owner->name ?: "no owner";
echo $val, "\r\n";
```

And you will get what you want.

Comment: I don't want to suppress errors (I didn't downvote btw, but this is not the approach I'm looking for)

Comment: this is not suppress the errors, it's just ignore the error which $dog->owner->name is not exists or black. and this is the shortest method.

Comment: this **is** suppressing the error & warning. Not advised to do so unless it's necessary. Hard to trace hidden errors.